# Pushing arrays into another array without duplicate values

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops, each

I've got an each loop within an each loop:

```
var data_array = [];

$('td.form').each(function(){

    $(this).children('input[type=hidden]').each(function(index, element){
        var name  = $(element).attr('name');
        data_array[index] = $(element).val();
    });

    console.log(data_array);

});
```

The first loop loops over a specific table cell which contains a set of hidden inputs.

I've managed to gather the data from the hidden inputs into arrays. When I write to console on each iteration, I get this:

```
[id: "56a8382bd5b88", date: "Tuesday, February 16th, 2016 - 10:00 PM UTC", waiting_list: "false"]
[id: "56a9260e14b3e", date: "Tuesday, February 23rd, 2016 - 5:00 PM UTC", waiting_list: "true"]
```

What I want to do is to write these arrays into a new array or object so I get something like this to use later on in the script:

```
myNewArray = [
    first = [ /* 'first' as placeholder text */
        id: "56a8382bd5b88", 
        date: "Tuesday, February 16th, 2016 - 10:00 PM UTC", 
        waiting_list: "false"
    ],
    second = [ /* 'second' as placeholder text */
        id: "56a9260e14b3e", 
        date: "Tuesday, February 23rd, 2016 - 5:00 PM UTC",  
        waiting_list: "true"
    ]
]
```

I've been experimenting with creating a new array and using push:

```
var data_array = [];
var myOtherNewArray = [];

$('td.form').each(function(){

    $(this).children('input[type=hidden]').each(function(index, element){
        var name  = $(element).attr('name');
        data_array[index] = $(element).val();
    });

    console.log(data_array);
    myOtherNewArray.push(data_array);

});

console.log(myOtherNewArray);
```

But this keeps giving me unwanted duplicates:

```
myOtherNewArray = [
    first = [
        id: "56a9260e14b3e",
        date: "Tuesday, February 23rd, 2016 - 5:00 PM UTC", 
        waiting_list: "true"
    ],
    second = [
        id: "56a9260e14b3e", 
        date: "Tuesday, February 23rd, 2016 - 5:00 PM UTC",  
        waiting_list: "true"
    ]
]
```

Obviously I'm overwriting the data in the loop.. I just can't seem to figure out the proper constuction here. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: where do you get the word `'first'`, or `'second'` from?

Comment: Could you create a jsFiddle with also the html part?

Comment: @NinaScholz, the words 'first' and 'second' are only placeholders (i.e. first array, second array, and so on)

Comment: maybe you clear the array before pushing the values. the code is not showing where the problem is taking place.

Answer (score -1):

This is a snippet of some extensions i made to the JavaScript Array prototype ... I hope it helps you. It is an Array.contains(item, [property]) function.

```
//returns boolean showing whether array contains an item, or if one of its 
//properties (arr[i].prop) is equal to item
Array.prototype.contains = function (item, prop) {
   var arr = this;
   if (prop == undefined || prop == null) {
       for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
           if (arr[i] == item) {
               return true;
           }
       }
   }
   else {
       for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
           if (arr[i][prop] == item) return true;
       }
   }
   return false;
}
```

With that, i believe you could check if the array contains a primitive object, or an object with a property that has a particular value.

If you wanted to check if an array contains the number 5, which Array.indexOf(5) could easily take care of,

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(arr.indexOf(5));
```

If you however wanted to check if the array contains an object with a property

```
var arr = [{name: "john", age: 11},{name: "paul", age: 11}];
console.log(arr.contains("paul", "name"));
```

That would print TRUE to the console.

EDIT: For making sure an array does not contain duplicate values, you would need an property to be the key, which in your case, i think is the property "id"
So, when iterating through the array, check if the result array contains an item whose "id" value is the same as the iteration item.

Comment: Why do you overcomplicate the code? Why don't you rely on the (optimised) searching done by indexOf and return  `index >= 0`? Why do you use equals, instead of strict equals? If my array contains both `"0"` and `0` as values, it will cause your solution to fail.

Comment: Well, i wrote that code ages, and i haven't edited it, except when i make adjustments. I'll make sure to use indexOf when next i come around to editing it. And i'm a huge fan of javascript's looseness, so "0" is the same as 0 to me.